# Using robot_localization with amcl

Tags: navigation, transforms, map-to-odom, robot-localization, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am starting to set up awesome [robot_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) package and I am using rotary encoders (`nav_msgs/Odometry`, both pose and twist) and IMU (`sensor_msgs/Imu`) which provides continuous data and [Ultrawide band sensor](http://www.decawave.com/products/evk1000-evaluation-kit) which provides global absolute position data as a `nav_msgs/Odometry` message (only pose, (x,y and yaw)) . As suggested on the wiki page of the package, I can fuse data from the encoders and the IMU in the `odom_frame` which gives the transform `odom_frame -> base_link_frame`. For the `map_frame`, I can fuse data from rotary_encoders, IMU and Ultrawide band sensor (It is similar to GPS in the sense that it provides global absolute position data) and it gives the transfrom from `map_frame -> odom_frame` but next I am using [amcl](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl) to improve the pose_estimate and amcl also provides `map_frame->odom_frame` transformation. So, I want to ask how should I deal with the transformations (specifically `map_frame->odom_frame`), Should I just not use the `map_frame->odom_frame` transformation from `robot_localization` and let amcl take care of it, If yes how can I not use the transformation? Or is there any better way to deal with it?

**Update 1:**
If I give output of AMCL and UWB to second instance of `ekf_localization_node`, it will give me the required transformation (`map_frame -> odom_frame`) and will publish the output odometry message on `odometry/filtered` topic but I am using [move_base](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base) which expects robot pose on `/amcl_pose` topic. So, I can remap the output on `odometry/filtered` to `amcl_pose` and change the message type from `nav_msgs/Odometry` to `geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped`, Does that sound okay?

Also, another approach which I am thinking is to run the first instance of `ekf_localization_node` (in `odom_frame`) with rotary encoders and IMU as input which will give `odom_frame->base_link_frame` transformation and then run second instance of `ekf_localization_node` (in `map_frame`) with UWB, rotary encoders and IMU as input. I am slightly confused about how the second instance will work. Will it modify the `odom_frame -> base_link_frame` tf by considering (or changing) the data from UWB in the `odom_frame`? If yes, then I can directly use the modified `odom_frame->base_link_frame` tf (which includes UWB, encoders and IMU) (and ignore `map_frame->odom_frame` tf from second instance of `ekf_localization_node`) in amcl and everything should be fine, right?

**Update 2:**
Thanks @Tom Moore for the answer! So just to clarify, run the first instance of `ekf_localization_node` in `odom_frame` with wheel odometry and IMU data as input which will give us the `odom_frame -> base_link_frame` transformation. Then run the second instance of the `ekf_localization_node` in the `map_frame` with wheel odometry, IMU data, UWB data (it is in `map_frame`) and `amcl_pose` which will give us the `map_frame -> odom_frame` transformation using existing `odom_frame -> base_link_frame` tf.

Thanks in advance.
Naman Kumar

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218137/using-robot_localization-with-amcl/) by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1464 on 2015-09-23

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-09-25**:
Re: edit 2, yes, sounds correct.

**Comment by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on 2015-09-25**:
Thanks a lot! :)

**Comment by [Punith](https://answers.ros.org/users/23098/punith/) on 2015-11-19**:
@Naman In this case, How are you setting the initial pose in amcl?  I mean do you use Rviz 2D Pose estimate or update the initial pose from UWB sensor as both are in map frame.

**Comment by [asimay_y](https://answers.ros.org/users/20955/asimay_y/) on 2016-06-14**:
hi, dear @Naman, did you solve this issue in reality? I'm doing same study on real UAV, but got very bad effect. could you please instruct me on this? thank you very much!

**Comment by [asimay_y](https://answers.ros.org/users/20955/asimay_y/) on 2016-06-14**:
dear @Naman, my issue is at here, i'm doing real experiment on UAV:
http://answers.ros.org/question/236403/tf-problems-when-combine-robot_localization-gps-navigation-amcl-stack/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One option would be to turn off the *map*->*odom* transform broadcast in `amcl`, and then include both `amcl` and the UWB sensor output as *inputs* to the second instance of `ekf_localization_node`. As long as they both report data in the same coordinate frame (or you provide the necessary transforms so they can), it should work.

> If I give output of AMCL and UWB to
> second instance of
> ekf_localization_node, it will give me
> the required transformation (map_frame
> -> odom_frame) and will publish the output odometry message on
> odometry/filtered topic but I am using
> move_base which expects robot pose on
> /amcl_pose topic. So, I can remap the
> output on odometry/filtered to
> amcl_pose and change the message type
> from nav_msgs/Odometry to
> geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped,
> Does that sound okay?

Yes, that's really the point of topic remapping. I would advise not remapping the output of the EKF to `/amcl_pose`, because you're using `/amcl_pose` as an input to the filter. Instead, do the remapping within the launch file for `move_base`, such that move_base now expects `/odometry/filtered`.

As far as your second question, read the frame descriptions [here](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization#Standard_Parameters). **Both** instances actually generate a transform from the `world_frame` to the `base_link_frame`, so **internally**, you have *map*->*base_link* and *odom*->*base_link*. But `tf` doesn't allow a frame to have two parents, so the second EKF instance automatically detects this situation (because `world_frame` and `map_frame` match) and uses its internal *map*->*base_link* transform, along with the existing *odom*->*base_link* transform that is broadcast by the first EKF instance, to produce a *map*->*odom* transform, which it then broadcasts. For your use case, I would make sure the UWB data has a `frame_id` of *map*.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2015-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on 2015-09-24**:
Thanks @Tom Moore for the answer. I have updated my original question, Can you look at it. Thanks!

**Comment by [asimay_y](https://answers.ros.org/users/20955/asimay_y/) on 2016-06-12**:
hi, dear @Tom Moore, i do as your instruction:

1. turn off map->odom tf transform in amcl;
   2.include amcl_pose topic and /odometry/gps topic as input to the second ekf_localization_global node;
2. remap move_base odom topic to /odometry/filtered;
   but get very bad effect. could you please instruct me